# Are you required to provide every icon size to release your app to the app store? iOS

Tags: ios, app-store

If you specify that an app is not universal (just for iPad or iPhone), do you still need to provide icons for both devices?

Comment: Since iPhone-only apps can be run on iPads, it's a good idea to have both in that case. But iPad-only apps can't be run on iPhones.

Comment: Try it and see!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apple’s iOS Human Interface Guidelines, every app must provide an icon to be displayed on a device’s Homescreen and in the App Store. An app should specify several different icons of different dimensions to suit different screen sizes and different situations.

You can save valuable time by using Makeappicon.com to generate app icons of all dimensions you need for submitting your apps to Apple in one click, no matter it’s built for iOS 7, iOS 8 and iOS 9, and focus on coding and improving your apps.